# Algorithm to check if first-order polynomial has any roots in region of the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, least-common-multiple

I'm trying to implement a C++ function to check if an object that refers to a tensor has the so-called problem of aliasing. This seems to lead to the following mathematical problem:

Assume you are given natural numbers $a_1,..., a_n > 0$ and $s_1,..., s_n > 1$. Do there exist integers $\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ not all equal to zero such that

$$\gamma_1 a_1 \; + \; ... \; + \; \gamma_n a_n = 0$$

and $-s_i < \gamma_i < s_i$ for all $i = 1,...n$.

I would need an efficient algorithm to check whether such $\gamma_i$'s exist or not. As $n$ refers to the dimension of a tensor, it is usually not too big but the $a_i, s_i$ can be big. So by *efficient* I mean that the algorithm should not just simply try all combinations.

For $n = 1$ it is of course trivial, and I think I also figured it out for $n = 2$, but $n > 2$ is giving me a bit of a headache.

I thought maybe this is a well-known mathematical problem with a well-known solution? Any hints, suggestions?

Comment: I just had a look at that Wikipedia page, but I don't think this problem fits the framework. The "other linear inequalities" that you mention seem to essentially rule out any solution that I would be interested in. But maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: Your problem is the same as $\min_{\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}^n}\sum_i \gamma_i a_i$ under the constraints $\sum_i \gamma_i a_i\ge 0$ and $\sum_i \gamma_i a_i\le 0$ and $\forall i, \gamma_i \in [-s_i+1,s_i-1]$ which is an [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem. The idea of IP is that relaxing to $\gamma$ real and adding more and more constraints to make $\gamma$ close to integer values, we can use the algorithms of linear programming to discard unfeasible regions.

Comment: @reuns GCD is also an integer programming problem, so there might be a more efficient algorithm for this.  Not that you are saying this particular problem is as hard as integer programming, of course.

Comment: Start by finding a basis of the sub-lattice $\{ \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}^n, \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \gamma_i=0\}$, then use some [lattice reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction) algorithm to find a basis of minimal Manhattan length @KyleMiller

Comment: @reuns Any hints on how I could find such a basis of the sub-lattice you mention?

Comment: @TobiasBrüll One way is to compute [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) for the $1\times n$ matrix given by the $a_i$'s, keeping track of the basis change matrix.

Comment: I don't see how you want to use SNF. Can't we do that : divide $a$ by $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, use the gcd algorithm to find one vector $v$ such that $\langle v, a\rangle=1$, find a basis $B$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ whose first column is $v$, then substract $\langle B_i, a\rangle v$ from all the other columns of $B$, obtaining $\langle B_i, a\rangle = 0$ for $i \ne 1$ and $B_2,\ldots,B_n$ is a basis of $\{ \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}^n, \langle  \gamma,a \rangle = 0\}$

Comment: @reuns I'm pretty sure you found the specialization of the SNF algorithm I had in mind.  Now, how does a minimal Manhattan length basis help solve the problem?

Comment: @KyleMiller [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) could be better than Manhattan. Once you have an almost orthogonal basis of minimal $\|.\|_2$ I think you can  enumerate the vectors with norm $\|.\|_1$ $\le d$ by saying $m \|u\|_2 \le \|u\|_1 \le M \|.\|_2$